# Copy subdirectories with the same name in windows 10

Tags: shell, windows-explorer, cmd.exe, file-management

On my Windows machine, `S` drive, under the `OF` folder I have the following structure :

```
S://OF
├── FolderA
│   └── FolderA1
│        └── FolderA2
│           └── FolderX
|                 └── myFolder  
│   
│             
├── FolderB
│   └── FolderB1
│        └── FolderB2
|              └── FolderX
|                    └── myFolder
│                
│             
├── FolderC
│   └── FolderC1
│        └── FolderC2
               └── FolderX
                     └── myFolder
```

I would like to copy all of the `myFolder` directories into a new directory (`AH`) on my `R` drive

```
R://AH
├── myFolder1
├── myFolder2   
├── myFolder3
```

I have tried the following but with no success!

```
For /D %G In ("OF\*") Do @%__AppDir__%Robocopy.exe "%G\myFolder" ".Destination\%~nxG_myFolder">NUL
```

Comment: Why not PowerShell? Do you need to search the whole drive or just sepecific folders? Does  `(gci s:\ MyFolder -ad -s).FullName` return the desired paths to the folders you want copied?

Comment: @KeithMiller, Nothing happening after running your command. Powershell just freezes and I have to close it!

Comment: Try step-by-step. `S:<enter>` should change the PowerShell prompt to the  `S:\ ` drive. `sl 0F<enter>` should navigare to the `0F` directory. Now try `gci MyFolder -Directory -recurse<enter>`. The folder name will need quotes if it contains spaces or special characters.

Comment: @KeithMiller, Nothing ! same as before. It freezes in the last step and does not show any results when I `run gci MyFolder -Directory -recurse<enter>`

Comment: what about one level at a time -- just `gci -directory`; `sl directory`, `gci -directroty` , etc. Maybe a permissions issue....

Answer (score 0):

This should do it for you, it traverses the folder tree using `dir`, when it finds a match creates the folder.

If you want to copy over or move the contents as well, replace `md` with any of `xcopy` or `copy` or `robocopy` depending on what you want to do.

```
@echo off

setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set "_pattern=MyFolder"

rem change this line to the fully qualified root of the tree where where your targets are:
set "_path=S drive path"

rem change this line to the fully qualified new location they will be copied to:
set "_newroot=R drive path"

rem loop through the tree where your the folders are:
for /f "delims="  %%i in ('dir "%_path%" /b /ad /s') DO (

  rem this is what you will compare to:
  @set "_foundpath=%%i"
  
  rem extract the last 'n' characters of the path found:
  call set _compareto=!_foundpath:~-8!

  rem if the folder pattern matches, perform the action:
  IF !_compareto!@ equ %_pattern%@ (
    set /a _cnt+=1
    rem  remove the echo in this line to make the directory:
    echo md %_newroot%\%_pattern%!_cnt!
  )
)
endlocal
exit /b
```

Comment: The answer assumes that there are no spaces in your folder names. If there are, place double quotes around the variables in the `IF` statement.